# how to make some property key as required from option in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I have one `Country` type and function like following. How can I create a new type that `Country` type include the required type `name`. so I do not have the error `TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Country'.`

```
export type Country<D extends object = {}> =
    | Car<D>;
    | People<D>;

export type People<D extends object = {}> =
    & ValueOf<{
        [K in keyof D]: {
            address: K;
        } & PersonWithOption<D, D[K]>;
    }>;

export interface PersonWithOption<D extends object = {}, V = any> {
    name?: string
}

function setDate(data: Country): Country {
  return data
}

const john = setDate({car: 'tesla', name:'john'})
expect(john.name).to.be('john')
//TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Country'.
```

I have tried to use something like

```
export type MandateProps<T extends {}, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
    [MK in K]-?: NonNullable<T[MK]>
}
export CountryWithName = MandateProps<Country, 'name'>
function setDate(data: Country | CountryWithName): Country | CountryWithName{
  return data
}
```

but I have the same error on
`expect(john.name).to.be('john')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setDate` function is enforcing that `data` be assignable to `Country`.  But you always just return `Country` regardless of what type `data` is.

If you want to get enforcement without losing specificity then all you need to do is make `setDate` a generic function.  This function checks that `typeof data extends Country` but it returns the same type that it was provided.

```
function setDate<D extends Country>(data: D): D {
  return data
}
```

```
const john = setDate({car: 'tesla', name:'john'})
const name = john.name;
```

Now it's ok to access `john.name` because `john` has type `{ car: string; name: string; }`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wXRvJm)